# В заданной строке найти самое длинное и самое короткое слово

Tags: c

Дано задание: В заданной строке найти самое длинное и самое короткое слово. Вывести их на экран и вывести их длину.

Самое длинное слово выводит, самое короткое нет, не получается, за длину слов даже и не пробовал выводить. Надеюсь на помощь, уже 5-й час ломаю мозг

Вот код:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
        char string[200];

        printf("Input a sentences: ");

        gets(string);

        char * pch = strtok (string," "),
             * maxword = 0,
             * minword = 0;

        int length = strlen(pch);

        int maxLen = 0;
        int minLen = 1000;

          while (pch != NULL)
          {
              length = strlen(pch);

              if (maxLen < length )
              {
                  maxLen = length;
                  maxword = pch;
              }

              pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
          }

          while (pch != NULL)
          {
              length = strlen(pch);

              if (minLen > length )
              {
                  minLen = length;
                  minword = pch;
              }

              pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
          }

          for(char *pch = strtok(string, " "); pch; pch = strtok(NULL, " "))
        {
            if(length < minLen)
            {
                minLen = length;
                minword = pch;
                strcpy(string,pch);
            }
        }
          printf("The longest word is: %s\n", maxword);
          printf("The least word is: %s\n", minword);

        return 0;
    }
    `
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде несколько ошибок, как фактических, так и стилистических, но
ответ на ваш вопрос можно свести к тому, что вы делаете в три цикла то,
что делается в один:

```c
for (char *word = strtok(s, delims); word != NULL;
     word = strtok(NULL, delims)) {
    size_t len = strlen(word);

    if (len > max_len) {
        max_len = len;
        max_word = word;
    }

    if (len < min_len) {
        min_len = len;
        min_word = word;
    }
}
```

Полный рабочий код:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

// size_t
// SIZE_MAX

#include <stdio.h>

// feof
// fflush
// fgets
// perror
// printf

#include <stdlib.h>

// NULL

#include <string.h>

// strtok
// strlen

enum { SIZE = 200 };

static const char delims[] = "\t\n\r ";

int main()
{
    char s[SIZE];

    printf("enter a sentence: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    char *res = fgets(s, SIZE, stdin);
    if (!res && !feof(stdin)) {
        perror("can't get the sentence");
        return 1;
    }

    char *max_word = NULL;
    char *min_word = NULL;

    size_t max_len = 0;
    size_t min_len = SIZE_MAX;

    for (char *word = strtok(s, delims); word != NULL;
         word = strtok(NULL, delims)) {
        size_t len = strlen(word);

        if (len > max_len) {
            max_len = len;
            max_word = word;
        }

        if (len < min_len) {
            min_len = len;
            min_word = word;
        }
    }

    printf("the longest word is: %s\n", max_word);
    printf("the shortest word is: %s\n", min_word);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Не ясно, почему вы ожидаете, что это вообще может работать. После завершения первого цикла `while` (поиск длинной строки) значение `pch` будет равно `NULL`. Второй цикл `while` (поиск короткой строки), разумеется, в такой ситуации будет просто пропущен.
2. Как я понял, вместо того, чтобы разбираться со вторым циклом, вы написали третий цикл `for`, который пытается делать то, что не смог сделать второй цикл `while`...

   Но функция `strtok` является *разрушающей* функцией - она модифицирует исходную строку путем замены некоторых символов на `\0`. Посте такой замены исходную строку уже невозможно обрабатывать повторным проходом все тем же `strtok`.

   Поэтому все ваши надежды на то, что вы сможете несколько раз пройтись по словам строки через `strtok` обречены на провал.

Если вы хотите, чтобы все ваши циклы работали через `strtok`, то вам придется каждому такому циклу предоставлять исходную, неповрежденную копию строки. Но лучше было бы обойтись без многочисленных проходов по строке. Для решения этой задачи одного прохода по исходной строке - более чем достаточно.

P.S. В стандартной библиотеке языка С уже давно нет функции `gets`.